# UpdateView that creates or increments existing instance

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a model that keeps track how much items have been "bought" at a certain value.
For example, one could think of items as stocks, value as the price they have been bought at.

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_version'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['item', 'value'], name='unique valued items')
        ]
```

Now, I'm trying to write a class-based `Create/UpdateView` in which one simply declares which item has been bought at what price. Then, the view should either create a new instance or increment an existing instance's quantity.

I already figured out that an `UpdateView` might be the best start as I can overwrite the `get_object` method to have this "create or update" behaviour.
However, I'm not sure how to do the incrementing.

Perhaps I'm also completely on the wrong track and there is a much simpler solution I am missing here.
It would be great to get some ideas and input on how to approach this problem.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [get_or_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method. It allows you to know it's new instance or from db. But if you want to create an api, it's the better way to use [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It ships with a lot of build-in tools for quick api creation.